# .mbtiles file with PBF to .mbtiles with PNG or JPEG

Tags: raster, openstreetmap, mbtiles, pbf

I need this conversion to embed the mbtiles file in a mobile app. I know there are server based rendering solutions, but I just need to make this conversion once for a single file with OpenStreetMap .pbf vectors. What is the easiest solution?

Answer (score 1):

### MBTiles images extract

in QGIS, there is a plugin specifically created for this purpose, called **MBTiles images extract**:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MBTiles2img/

Make sure you install it on QGIS 3 or newer:

1. Install QGIS, if you haven't done so yet
2. `Plugin` menu -> `Manage and install plugin` -> type 'MBTiles'
3. `Install Plugin`

Comment: With QGIS I'm not able to change the output extension of the file. As the MBtiles file contain pbf's file the outcome is *.pbf tiles. How can I change them to *.png?